# Two metrics with same topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $M =[1,\infty)$ and let $d_1,d_2:M\times M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be two metrics defined by $$d_1(x,y)=|x-y|,\quad d_2(x,y)=|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|.$$
Prove they induce the same topology.
I already showed that all open sets in $(M,d_1)$ are also open sets in $(M,d_2)$ by showing that all open balls with $d_1$ contain a ball with $d_2$. But i am struggling with the other way.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to show that the open balls of d1 are in balls in d2 and vice versa. I already showed that the balls of d2 are in d1. But i am stuck at the other direction.

Comment: It is easy to show that $d_1$ dominates $d_2$. (You have a typo.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sufficient to show that an open ball around $x$ in one topology contains an open ball around $x$ in the other topology.

Let $r>0$.

Suppose $y \in B_1(x,r)$, then $d_2(x,y) = {|x-y| \over |xy|} \le |x-y| = d_1(x,y) < r$ and so $B_1(x,r) \subset B_2(x,r)$.

Now suppose we are given $B_1(x,r)$, we want to find some $r'$ such that
$B_2(x,r') \subset B_1(x,r)$.

Choose $r'=\min({1 \over 2x}, {r \over 2 x^2})$.
(Note that if $d_2(x,y) < {1 \over 2x}$ then $y < 2x$.)

Suppose $y \in B_2(x,r')$, then
$d_1(x,y) = |x-y| = |xy|{|x-y| \over |xy|} < 2x^2 d_2(x,y) \le r$
and so $y \in B_1(x,r)$.

Note that while the topologies are the same, the Cauchy sequences are different. For example, $x_n = n$ is not Cauchy with $d_1$ but is Cauchy in $d_2$. In particular, $(M,d_1)$ is complete but $(M,d_2)$ is not.

**Addendum**: To see why $d_2(x,y) < {1 \over 2x}$ implies $y < 2x$:
If ${1 \over x}  - {1 \over y} \le | {1 \over x}  - {1 \over y} | = d_2(x,y) < {1 \over 2x}$, then ${1 \over 2x} < {1 \over y}$ and so
$y < 2x$.

Comment: Thanks very much!! But I have a question i don't understand the inequality in your second step that |x-y| <= U^2... i would would be happy if you could help me with this

Comment: The topologies are the same but one space is complete and the other is not? That is the first I have heard of this being possible...interesting.

Comment: @DanielBanov: Sorry, I meant to elaborate. Note that $|xy| \le U^2$, so $U^2 {1 \over |xy|} \ge 1$.

Comment: @Math1000: It is a fairly standard observation used to distinguish metric spaces from topological spaces, the usual example is $d_1$ above and $d_2(x,y)=|\arctan x - \arctan y|$.

Comment: @copper.hat sorry i'm still a bit at a loss, I tried to rearange the inequality $|xy|\leq U^2$ for 20 minutes but I still don't see why it should hold

Comment: @DanielBanov: I think I goofed. Let me see if I can find a quick repair.

Comment: @DanielBanov: Apologies, I made a number of egregious errors. Hopefully only small ones remain...

Comment: @DanielBanov: I added an explanation at the end of the question.

Comment: Note that in general the $B_2(x,r')$ ball is not even bounded in a $d_1$ sense, so to make the above work, I need to (at least) choose $r'$ small enough so that $B_2(x,r')$ is bounded.

Comment: Thank you very much I understood the whole thing now :)